# How to install Windows 10 alongside my already installed Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I would like to have a W10 boot option alongside my Ubuntu.
I have a 500GB SSD as my only disk on this computer.
I have backed up all my files already, I can restart from scratch if needed.
When I installed this OS a month ago, I selected the "classic" installation, and so my disk has not been partitioned in any particular way.
50GB should be enough for what I want to do with W10.

I would like to know the procedure to do so.

Do I need to reinstall Ubuntu and select some specific options to free some partition space for w10 ? Or can I straight up boot my w10 stick and see from there ?

Please elaborate your answer, I am not too familiar with this layer as I have studied algorithms.
Thank you so very much for your help.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS (Legacy/CSM) mode? Hopefully UEFI in which case the short story is boot a live session, shrink partition, boot Windows installation, select unallocated space, install.

Comment: In my BIOS Setup>Boot Options, I have a Boot Mode : UEFI Only.
I can see UEFI mentioned in my boot order sequence too.
1: ubuntu
2: UEFI KBG40 ZNS512G NVMe KIOXIA 521GB 60JPDFXUPTML1
3: Linux Firmware Updater

So it seems this is UEFI mode. How do I shrink the partition ? From the live usb ubuntu ?

Comment: Perfect. You can install Windows, let it finish everything including updates, expect many reboots (directly to Windows), disable Fast Startup and shutdown Windows. Next boot open UEFI settings and change the boot order back to Ubuntu.

Comment: You, typically you'd use GParted in a Ubuntu live session to safely shrink the main Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One last question just to be safe : where/how do I disable Fast Startup inside the Windows ?

Comment: That's a Windows question and honestly Google can give that answer in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Correct I found it, thank you very much ! <3

Comment: I found it's easiest to install Windows first and Ubuntu second.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)